# How can I launch a graphic program from a docker container in Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: docker, ubuntu, graphics, operating-system

I follow the next steps:

```
nano Dockerfile
   FROM UBUNTU:22.10
   RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y firefox
   CMD /usr/bin/firefox

docker build -t firefox .

xhost +

docker run -d --name firefox -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix firefox
```

If I launch the logs of the container with "docker logs firefox", I get:

```
Command '/usr/bin/firefox' requires the firefox snap to be installed.
Please install it with:
snap install firefox
```

About that, I change the Dockerfile in a lot of ways but I can't get the correct configuration:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.04
ENV container docker
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y systemd systemd-sysv
RUN apt-get install -y snapd
RUN systemctl enable --now snapd.socket
RUN snap wait system seed.loaded
RUN snap install firefox
CMD /usr/bin/firefox
```

Another reason of the problem could be that the **/tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix**  is another route in Ubuntu 22.04.

Answer (score 1):

According to this [thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1399383/how-to-install-firefox-as-a-traditional-deb-package-without-snap-in-ubuntu-22), it's possible to install firefox without snap.

Here is the simplest solution using firefox-esr in your Dockerfile:

```
FROM ubuntu:22.10
RUN  apt update -yq \
     && apt install -yq software-properties-common \
     && add-apt-repository ppa:mozillateam/ppa \
     && apt-get update \
     && apt-get install -y firefox-esr \
     && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
CMD /usr/bin/firefox-esr
```

Comment: Thanks Hostou, I try it not launch the inteface.

I try with:
    xhost +
    docker run -d --name firefox -e DISPLAY=$DISPLAY -v /tmp/.X11-unix:/tmp/.X11-unix firefox

Also I try with only "docker run -it firefox" and I get "Error: no DISPLAY environment variable specified"